# Change value in string instead of hard coding

Tags: php, mysql

Experts is there any option to automatically increase +1 in `category_level`

for ex: `$cond_cat=" where category_level='1' and ID='$sleads' ";`   than `$cond_cat=" where category_level='2' and parent_id ='$sleads' ";`

my code is given below.

```
 <?php
    include('classes/global.php');
    $CT=new Product();
    $AdminObj=new Admin();
    $sleads=$_REQUEST['sleads'];
    $cond_cat=" where category_level='1' and ID='$sleads' ";
    $catResult_cond=$CT->getCategory($cond_cat);
    $cond_cat=" where category_level='2' and parent_id ='$sleads' ";
    $subCatResult_cond=$CT->getCategory($cond_cat);

    ?>
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `where category_level=category_level+1` ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to recursively get subcategories as a child of the subcategory you are into.

```
<?php

  function getSubCategories($level) {
    // you should obviously get the $sleads variable in here, for this to work.
    $cond_cat = "where category_level='%d' and ID='$sleads' ";
    $subcategories = $CT->getCategory(sprintf($cond_cat, $level));
    if (count($subcategories) > 0) {
      foreach($subcategories as $subcategory) {
        $subcategory->subcategories = $CT->getCategory(sprintf($cond_cat, $level+1));
      }
    }
    return $subcategories;
  }

  $i = 1;
  $categories = getSubCategories($i);

?>
```

This will get you something like:

```
// $categories         // first level
// foreach($categories as $cat) {
  // $cat->subcategories // second level categories
  // foreach($cat->subcategories as $subcategory) {
    // $subcategory->subcategories // third level
  // }
// }
// and so on
```

Please take into account that I assume that your `$CT->getCategory` function returns an array of category records.
If that is not the case (taking into consideration that you also add an ID="" in your query), you should also alter that function, or use a function that returns multiple category records.